# Stop Dracut from asking for a password

Tags: centos, raid, luks, dracut

I have a device I've encrypted with luks1 and I decrypt it with a script in `init.d`. (Centos 6, no keyscript in crypttab). Its a raid disk, with the encryption under the raid, but I don't think that matters.

The `lsblk` looks like:

```
sda                                   8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
└─md127                               9:127  0 476.7G  0 raid0 
  └─luksmap1 (dm-15)                253:15   0 476.7G  0 crypt /data11
sdb                                   8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk  
└─md127                               9:127  0 476.7G  0 raid0 
  └─luksmap1 (dm-15)                253:15   0 476.7G  0 crypt /data1
```

The problem is that dracut finds it during boot and asks for a password. I need to be able reboot this without being physically present.

It's set to `noauto` in `fstab`. I've told dracut not to load `/etc/mdadm.conf`. `cryptab` is empty.

How do I tell dracut not to look for ask for the password? Or timeout after waiting a bit? Or just keep going if there's no keyboard present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely prevent dracut from scanning for LUKS devices, add the following to your kernel command line:

```
rd.luks=0
```

If you want to only decrypt specific disks (e.g. I wanted it to decrypt the root partition, but not other encrypted disks), you should instead add

```
rd.luks.uuid=<DISK_UUID_HERE>
```

once per encrypted disk and **not** add `rd.luks=0`. You can find the UUIDs for disks with `lsblk -o +uuid`.

More on the options can be found in the manpage [`dracut.cmdline(7)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html).

Comment: I can't verify if this worked, because I've unfortunately no longer have access to the system. I've accepted this as the correct answer but will leave this comment for anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: I've tried it before posting, as I came about this question while needing this myself. I added the manpage documenting these options to the answer.